# Alternative Proof to the Proposition that $\forall y>0$,$\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $n-1 \leq y < n$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Prove: If $y > 0$, then there exists a natural number $n$ such that $n-1 \leq y < n$.

I know that one could prove this proposition using the well-ordering principle on the set $\{m \in \mathbb{N} \, : \, y < m\}$, but I was wondering if the following proof is also valid.

My approach is one of cases where we consider $\mathbb{R^+} = \mathbb{Q^+} \cup \mathbb{J^+}$, where $\mathbb{J^+}$ is the set of positive irrational numbers.

Suppose that $y \in \mathbb{Q^+}$. Between any two real numbers $x$ and $z$  where $x < z$, we have the inequality $x < y < z$ (since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$). Setting $x = n-1$ and $z = n$, we have the desired inequality $n-1 < y < n$. The same also holds if $y \in \mathbb{J^+}$ (because $\mathbb{J}$ is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$).

Because we considered all cases where $y > 0$, we can conclude that the given proposition is true.

Any thoughts?

**Update** Deleted the case where $y \in \mathbb{N}$, since it was included in the case $y \in \mathbb{Q^+}$.

Comment: It's unclear where $x$ and $z$ come from. Are they arbitrary real numbers below and above $y$? If so what guarantees that $x$ is a natural number, as $x=n-1$ seems the suggest?

Comment: How are you deducing the (false) conclusion that between any two real numbers $x$ and $z$ we have $x < y < z$?

Comment: @daron Yeah, I should have mentioned that $x <  z$. Furthermore, because the Archimedean property applies for every real number $x$, I can universally instantiate $x$ to be any number of my choosing, namely $n-1$.

Comment: @RobArthan I need to put in my proof that $x < z$. From that assumption, I am using the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, but given $y$ (e.g., $y = 50$), you can't conclude that $x < y < z$ for any $x$ and $z$ with $x < z$ (e.g., $x = 1$ and $z = 2$).

Comment: What if we began with using the lemma that if $x$ and $z$ are positive real numbers with $x < z$, then there exists a real number $y$ such that $x < y < z$?

Comment: That doesn't help: $y$ is given to us as part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem with your proof is that you're incorrectly applying density of $\Bbb Q^+$ and $\Bbb J^+$ in $\Bbb R^+.$ You have *started* with an arbitrary *but fixed* $y$ (in one of these two sets), then taken an apparently arbitrary $x,z\in\Bbb R^+$ with $x<y<z,$ and then claimed without justification that we can simply take $x=n-1$ and $z=n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N.$

What density allows us to do is *start* with some natural number $n,$ then conclude that there is *some* $y\in\Bbb Q^+$ (or $y\in\Bbb J^+$) such that $n-1<y<n.$ However, we cannot be certain that your previously-fixed $y$ satisfies this property, as that's what we're trying to prove!

Comment: I see my error and understand your important points. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome!